# How to create a WCF service without the need of a Service Certificate?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I'm trying to create a basic webservice with WCF. It's small, and will only be used internally between two servers, so there is no need for security of any kind. Unfortunately WCF demands a certificate:

> The service certificate is not provided. Specify a service certificate in ServiceCredentials.

I don't want to configure a certificate anywhere. Certificates are great for security, but also invariably come packaged with two days worth of headaches until you get them right *just so*, and I don't want that right now.

I'm googling all around but cannot find an answer anywhere - can you disable this feature of WCF?

**Added:** Almost forgot, here's my bindings 'n stuff, just in case they're useful:

```
<bindings>
  <wsFederationHttpBinding>
    <binding name="XXXServiceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="1073741824" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </wsFederationHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="XXXServiceBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="XXX.XXX" behaviorConfiguration="XXXServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="xxx" contract="XXX.IXXX" binding="wsFederationHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="XXXServiceBinding">
      <identity>
        <dns value="XXX Test Service"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

Added 2: Oh, right, VS2010, .NET 4.0. Windows 7, integrated VS webserver.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the steps? Were you using Visual Studio? Where exactly did you get this issue? You may post the code.

Comment: I took an existing (pretty simple) WCF webservice, and deleted everything from it until a basic skeleton remained, which I filled with my own webservice. Right now it contains a single service interface, a single class that implements this interface, a couple of helper classes (non-WCF related), and the web.config. This is all that is actually inside the web.config, aside from a few irrelevant appSettings.

Comment: So you have the answers. All of the answers point to the same. The binding is not appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What does your `web.config` bindings section look like? Using `basicHttpBinding` with `clientCredentialType="None"` should as far as I know run without any certificates. Ie:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceWS">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
   ....
```

Comment: This still requires certificate for HTTPS.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka: Changed to `<security mode="None">`, that should do it, right?

Comment: Yay! It work'd! Didn't even need any of that `<security>` stuff.

Comment: Great. security is None by default, so that makes sense. (and without security no need for transport settings).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use security why are you using `WsFedarationBinding` which is designed for federated security? Use `BasicHttpBinding` instead. It doesn't use any security by default or if all communication will be performed in the same windows domain with users and service using domain accounts you can use `WsHttpBinding` with default configuration - it will use Windows security without need for any certificate.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `wsFederationHttpBinding` in the service. If it is not important to push in so much of security, you could have gone for simple HTTP binding called `basicHTTP` binding. Consider appropriate binding for the service.

Comment: What are bindings? :) OK, I'll try that.

Comment: @Vilx-: You need to clear the basic configuration concepts in WCF. That will make you comfortable. See the answer from Avada here for the config settings.

Comment: @Vilx: *What are bindings?* Man, if you want to use technology shouldn't you read at least some introduction? Understanding what is [WCF ABC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480190.aspx) could be a good start.